# Python how to split the screen

Tags: python, split, python-requests, bots, screen

i have a problem

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWClk.png)

There is 3 same picture on the diffrent browsers. I want to process each one separately. How can i split them ?

I'm beginner on python, i'm start new and i tried something like this:

```
while 1:
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(IMG_1):
    click(101, 488)
    sleep(1)
    print("clicking")
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(IMG_2): ## After than img_1, img_2 comes the screen
        click(205, 689)
        sleep(1)
        print("img_2 done")
```

This is works only 1 browser.

Comment: Please add the screenshot inline in the post, for example by dragging the image file into the input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im got confused trying to understand if you want to split the image and put each one in different browsers. After that, I wrote this:

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

img_1 = "1st.png"
img_2 = "2nd.png"
img_3 = "3th.png"

def click(pos):
    pyautogui.moveTo(pos)
    sleep(.5)
    pyautogui.click()

while True:
    try:
        pos_img_1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_1)
        pos_img_2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_2)
        pos_img_3 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img_3)

        if pos_img_1 != None:
            sleep(.5)
            click(img_1)
            print("Clicking...")

        if pos_img_2 != None:
            sleep(.5)
            click(img_2)
            print("Clicking...")
        
        if pos_img_3 != None:
            sleep(.5)
            click(img_3)
            print("Clicking...")
          
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

Here are the split images > https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdBcU.jpg

Comment: Thank you but images are the same. Sorry for bad explain xd.